# REST resources defined in UrlMappings results in 404

Tags: rest, grails, url-mapping, grails-3.0

Using grails 3.0.9, I've defined 2 Domains:

```
Game -> hasMany plays
Play -> belongsTo game
```

I've added the following to my UrlMappings.groovy file.

```
"/games"(resources: "game") {
  "/plays"(resources: "play")
}
```

Using Postman, I'm doing a get on `http://localhost:8080/games` and I get a `404`.

If I remove the UrlMappings and place an `@Resource(uri='/games')` on the `Game` domain, it returns a 200, as expected. Here is what I get when I run url-mappings-report:

```
Dynamic Mappings
 |    *     | ERROR: 404                                        | View:   /notFound        |
 |    *     | ERROR: 500                                        | View:   /error           |
 |    *     | /                                                 | View:   /index           |
 |    *     | /${controller}/${action}?/${id}?(.${format)?      | Action: (default action) |

Controller: game
 |   GET    | /games/create                                     | Action: create           |
 |   GET    | /games/${id}/edit                                 | Action: edit             |
 |   POST   | /games                                            | Action: save             |
 |   GET    | /games                                            | Action: index            |
 |  DELETE  | /games/${id}                                      | Action: delete           |
 |  PATCH   | /games/${id}                                      | Action: patch            |
 |   PUT    | /games/${id}                                      | Action: update           |
 |   GET    | /games/${id}                                      | Action: show             |

Controller: play
 |   GET    | /games/${gameId}/plays/create                     | Action: create           |
 |   GET    | /games/${gameId}/plays/${id}/edit                 | Action: edit             |
 |   POST   | /games/${gameId}/plays                            | Action: save             |
 |   GET    | /games/${gameId}/plays                            | Action: index            |
 |  DELETE  | /games/${gameId}/plays/${id}                      | Action: delete           |
 |  PATCH   | /games/${gameId}/plays/${id}                      | Action: patch            |
 |   PUT    | /games/${gameId}/plays/${id}                      | Action: update           |
 |   GET    | /games/${gameId}/plays/${id}                      | Action: show             |
```

Not sure why the UrlMappings are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is the UrlMappings syntax `"/games"(resources: "game")` automatically generates the associated RESTful mappings (and only the mappings), while the use of the `@Resource(uri='/games')` syntax generates the controller/actions.

With the `"/games"(resources: "game")`, you still need to define your own controller.  The way you've written this question, I get the feeling that you haven't done this.

Comment: I haven't. But the docs suggest otherwise. I'll look into that.

Comment: From the docs: If you prefer to keep the declaration of the URL mapping in your UrlMappings.groovy file then simply removing the uri attribute of the Resource transformation and adding the following line to UrlMappings.groovy will suffice. Which would imply no controller since the resource transformation doesn't require one. So either the docs are wrong or I didn't do something else correctly.

Comment: Oh snap. I just read it again. The Resource is still required on the domain. It's just the URI attribute gets removed.

Comment: I was honestly confused myself when I first ran into the documentation, I use the `@Resource` annotation with the URI.